# Bootstrap align Input group horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following form and want the input-group to be aligned horizontally.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Mixed Form</h2>
  <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">  
       <div class="input-group-btn"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Frau <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Herr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frau</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <label>Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
   </div>
        
 
      <div class="col-sm-2"><label>Tel.</label><input class="form-control" placeholder="Tel." type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><label>E-mail</label><input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" type="text"></div>
    </div>
<br><br><br>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr>
</div>
```

thankful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Mixed Form</h2>
  <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>Name</label>
          <div class="input-group">            
       <div class="input-group-btn">            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Frau <span class="caret"></span></button>        
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Herr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frau</a></li>
        </ul>
          
            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
           
                      
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
          
   </div>
        
 
      <div class="col-sm-2"><label>Tel.</label><input class="form-control" placeholder="Tel." type="text"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><label>E-mail</label><input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" type="text"></div>
    </div>
<br><br><br>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, asuming you can change your html, you may NOT contain both your first `select` and next `input`(plus `label`) under same parent.

You could just make a container for the select with same class for margins, responsivness, etc (`col-sm-2`) and another for the `label`+ `input`under same class.

Then just add a `label`before the `select` with a `&nbsp`to make the distances the same.

Here you have a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/da1pxtsj/)**

I have removed both:

```
<div class="input-group">  
    <div class="input-group-btn"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

as in your example it were just useless containers messing around.

Comment: You removed the input-group (connected fields) which i do need.

Comment: Then add it again and be sure those classes don't mess the layout and if it does be ready to use css to overwritte boostrap css's. If you don't want to learn css's then you may know the limits of bootstrap and adapt to what it can offer (and more often, what it CAN not)